# Make TypeScript aware of a conditionally returning Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Let's say you have a Component, that basically looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export type ConditionalRenderProps = {
  condition: boolean | undefined | null;
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export function ConditionalRender({ condition, children }: ConditionalRenderProps): JSX.Element | null {
  if (condition) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Now you have another component like this:

```
type EditModeValues = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

type CreateModeValues = {
  name: string;
}

type EditForm = {
  isEditMode: true;
  data: EditModeValues;
};

type CreateForm = {
  isEditMode: false;
  data: CreateModeValues;
}

export type FormProps = EditForm | CreateForm;

function Form({ isEditMode, data }: FormProps) {

  return (
    <>
      <ConditionalRender condition={isEditMode}>
        <p>{data.id}</p>
      </ConditionalRender>
      <p>{data.id}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Now TypeScript will complain, that `data.id` does not exist on CreateModeValues, as it does not know that the `ConditionalRender` Component works like an if statement and checks if its an edit mode. Is there a way to tell TypeScript that the `ConditionalRender` does only return the children, if the condition is true so it could correctly infer that the children are only being rendered with the `EditForm` type?

Using

```
{isEditMode && <p>{data.id}</p>}
```

would work and then TypeScript would infer all types correctly but we'd love to have TS infer the types of the ConditionalRender correctly as this component makes it easier to work with conditions.

I've also tried working with Generics refactoring the ConditionalRender to smth like this:

```
export type ConditionalRenderProps<T extends boolean> = {
  condition: T;
  children: T extends true ? React.ReactNode : null;
};

export function ConditionalRender<T extends boolean>({ condition, children }: ConditionalRenderProps<T>) {
  if (condition) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }

  return null;
}
```

which also didn't yield the expected result.

Comment: Whether `ConditionalRender` returns its children or not doesn't even matter here, you're accessing `data.id` either way.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use an if condition, it won't know the actual `data` type.

If you want to keep your data structure the same as it's right now,
then add this `id?: undefined` to `CreateModeValues` to solve your problem, like this:

```js
type CreateModeValues = {
 id?: undefined;
 name: string;
}
```

---

What I normally do to avoid creating many data types, and just keep things simple and more unified, is something that would look like this:

```js
interface FormValues {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
}
```

then If data has an id, then it's definitly in edit mode.

```
function Form(data: FormValues ) {
  const editMode = !!data.id;

  return (
    <>
      <ConditionalRender condition={editMode}>
        <p>{data.id}</p>
      </ConditionalRender>
      <p>{data.id}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```